# Blind source separation for asynchronously observed mixture channels

Tags: continuous-signals, source-separation, inverse-problem, ica, blind-deconvolution

Given your practical and theoretical expertise: Does ICA work reliably when applied to a multidimensional mixture (observation) $X = (X^1, \cdots, X^d)$ if the different channels $X^i$ of the observation aren't recorded synchronously?

I.e., if there are time-delays between the different channels of the observation, so that instead of
$$(X^1_{t_j^1}, \cdots, X^d_{t^d_j}) \quad \text{ with } \quad t^1_j=\ldots=t^d_j \quad \forall\, j$$

one observes

$$(X^1_{t^1_j}, \cdots, X^d_{t^d_j}) \quad \text{ with } \quad t^k_j\neq t^l_j \quad (k\neq l) \quad \text{for most } j.$$

Note that in contrast to [this question](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/1103/how-does-ica-handle-inevitable-delays-in-signals?rq=1) and [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/812/fail-to-separate-sound-signals-by-fastica-on-real-world-recording?noredirect=1&lq=1&newreg=38db1c2e86b94a5e834ea16bd3668253), we assume as usual that every channel observation $X^i_t$ is obtained without delays in its constituent (independent) sources $S^1, \ldots, S^d$, i.e. that $X^i_t = a_{11} S^i_t + \ldots + a_{1d} S^i_t$ for some $a_{11}, \ldots, a_{1d}\in\mathbb{R}$ at any time $t$.

Comment: It depends on whether the asynchronicity violates any of ICA's assumptions, such as the source signals are IID non-Gaussian. Delaying a whole channel obviously won't change the distribution of anything, but will shifted versions be viewed as independent? One way to fix such a problem (if it is a problem) would be to find the delays between the channels via cross correlation, and compensate for them before doing ICA.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, @Gillespie!

Comment: Sure, let us know if you learn anything more. It would be easy to simulate and test, so maybe eventually I'll get around to that.

Comment: I will, thanks -- and sure it would be exciting to hear about any empirical findings that you might come across!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on a few quick experiments, ICA fails when the channels are delayed relative to each other. It's fairly easy to test in MATLAB (or no doubt other software packages) with [FastICA](http://research.ics.aalto.fi/ica/fastica/) (or [Robust ICA](https://www.i3s.unice.fr/%7Ezarzoso/robustica.html), which handles complex data). Here's a quick example with no time offsets between the channels:

```
[sig, mixedsig] = demosig(); 

N = size(sig, 1);       %Number of source signals
M = size(mixedsig, 1);  %Number of channels 

%Find mixing matrix as a right sided inverse
A0 = mixedsig/sig; 

%Do ICA
[icasig, A, W] = fastica(mixedsig); 

%Plot the original signals, and the ICA seperation
figure; icaplot('classic', sig);        title('Original Signals')
figure; icaplot('classic', mixedsig);   title('Mixed Signals')
figure; icaplot('classic', icasig);     title('Fast ICA')
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

As you can see, ICA did a pretty good job separating the signals (to within a sign). But if we add a delay between the channels as you suggested, this is what we get:

```
%Now delay the channels and try again
dels = randi(100, 4, 1); 
mixedsig2 = zeros(size(mixedsig, 1), size(mixedsig, 2) + max(dels)); 
for k = 1:4
    mixedsig2(k, dels(k)+1:dels(k) + size(mixedsig, 2)) = mixedsig(k,:); 
end

[icasig2, A2, W2] = fastica(mixedsig2); 
figure; icaplot('classic', icasig2);     title('Fast ICA: Shifted Channels')
```

[image]

So ICA appears to break down when you shift the channels. I also tried circularly shifting the data, and got the same results.

Comment: How can you ever have a realistic case where there is not a delay between the channels? For there not to be means that all of the sources are equidistant to all of the receivers. Am I wrong here? I am looking at the BSS model and I cannot see where it allows for signal to reach receiver $i$ and at different time that it reaches receiver $j$.

Comment: I have asked exactly that question here:https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/82978/55647. ICA fails for "significant" delays, but the question  is how significant?